# scrapy :if FormRequest have jsessionid

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I practice FormRequest and have a problem
Fisrt,I crawl a link in def(parse),and I wiil get a json back in def(parse1).
Then I got the `actId` in json which I can yield request to crawl other links ,but there is error like this:

```
 ERROR: Spider error processing <POST http://xxx.tw/ca/to.do;jsessionid=A69C5203A49A12DA450F32E6B2AB0E23?mtd=Search&mId=604>

 exceptions.TypeError: unicode_to_str must receive a unicode or str object, got int
```

I think it is because it deliver a jsessionid `jsessionid=A69C5203A49A12DA450F32E6B2AB0E23`

Because I try `yield FormRequest(url='http://xxx.tw/ca/toView?mtd=do', callback=self.parse3, formdata={'actId': actId})`  desperately,and it works well.

Here is Code:

```
 def parse(self, response):
    yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                    formname='Form',
                                    formdata={'when': '9',
                                              'key': 'please input',
                                             },
                                    callback=self.parse1)
   #<form name="Form" id="search" method="post" action="/ca/to?mtd=do&Id=4">
 def parse1(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.body)
    tryone =  data.get('to')
    for i in tryone:
        actId = i['actId']
        yield FormRequest(url='http://xxx.tw/ca/toView?mtd=do', callback=self.parse3, formdata={'actId': actId})  

 def parse3(self, response): 
    print response.status   #200
    print 'haha'
```

How can I do to solve the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the type of actId ? If it is int than convert actId to string from int. In latest versions of scarpy it requires conversion.

```
    yield FormRequest(url='http://xxx.tw/ca/toView?mtd=do', callback=self.parse3, formdata={'actId': str(actId)})
```